# Give Python root permissions in AWS SageMaker Jupyter Labs

Tags: python, elasticsearch, machine-learning, lambda, chown

I'm using this [Notebook](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/master/tutorials/Tutorial16_Document_Classifier_at_Index_Time.ipynb), where section **Apply DocumentClassifier** is altered as below.

**Jupyter Labs**, kernel: `conda_mxnet_latest_p37`.

---

`chown` command outputting many: `Operation not permitted` and `preexec_fn` lambda function errors.

Adding `sudo...` on `chown` line doesn't output any `Operation not permitted` but still throws `SubprocessError`:

```
! sudo chown -R daemon:daemon elasticsearch-7.9.2
```

Running `os.setuid(1)` throws a `PermissionError`.

**How can I give Python root user permissions in my AWS SageMaker Jupyter Labs?**

I suspect this may be the reason for my errors.

---

**My Code:**

```py
# In Colab / No Docker environments: Start Elasticsearch from source
! wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -q
! tar -xzf elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
! chown -R daemon:daemon elasticsearch-7.9.2

import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
es_server = Popen(['elasticsearch-7.9.2/bin/elasticsearch'],
                   stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
                   preexec_fn=lambda: os.setuid(1)  # as daemon
                  )
# wait until ES has started
! sleep 30
```

**Error:**

```
...
chown: changing ownership of ‘elasticsearch-7.9.2/modules/x-pack-enrich’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘elasticsearch-7.9.2/modules’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘elasticsearch-7.9.2’: Operation not permitted
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SubprocessError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5f043305a2ca> in <module>
      8 es_server = Popen(['elasticsearch-7.9.2/bin/elasticsearch'],
      9                    stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
---> 10                    preexec_fn=lambda: os.setuid(1)  # as daemon
     11                   )
     12 # wait until ES has started

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    798                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:
    802             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1550                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
   1551                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
-> 1552                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1553 
   1554 

SubprocessError: Exception occurred in preexec_fn.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SubprocessError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5f043305a2ca> in <module>
      8 es_server = Popen(['elasticsearch-7.9.2/bin/elasticsearch'],
      9                    stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
---> 10                    preexec_fn=lambda: os.setuid(1)  # as daemon
     11                   )
     12 # wait until ES has started

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    798                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:
    802             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1550                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
   1551                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
-> 1552                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1553 
   1554 

SubprocessError: Exception occurred in preexec_fn.
```

**Running `os.setuid(1)` on it's own:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-05c09af034fe> in <module>
----> 1 os.setuid(1)

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-05c09af034fe> in <module>
----> 1 os.setuid(1)

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I've made an [Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1380103/1327111), regarding the `chown` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting os.setuid(0)

os.setuid() method is used to set the current process’s real user id. Set real user ID of the current process using os.setuid() method.

```py
# In Colab / No Docker environments: Start Elasticsearch from source
! wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -q
! tar -xzf elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
! chown -R daemon:daemon elasticsearch-7.9.2

import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

es_server = Popen(
    ["elasticsearch-7.9.2/bin/elasticsearch"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, preexec_fn=lambda: os.setuid(0)  # as daemon
)
# wait until ES has started
! sleep 30
```